# How to run ".iim" file with Google Chrome from commandline?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, imacros

How can I run `.iim` file with Google Chrome from commandline?

Comment: View "Command Line Support" on the "iMacros for Chrome" wiki page: http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome

Comment: I think you should switch to FireFox. I've read about Chrome and iMacros and it's complicated to run iMacros from command line.

Comment: @Shugar Thank you for the link. But it says that that solution is not working anymore.

Comment: @macroscripts I know that Firefox is working much better but I am using Chrome and need to automate Chrome.

Comment: I know it can be done with FireFox and bookmarks. Try the same with Chrome.